# Calling web service operation via SOAP with smartGWT client application

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf, smartgwt

I have problem with calling web service operation via SOAP with smartGWT client application.

I have two applications running on same TomCat server:

1. web service with some operations defined by wsdl (generated by apache CXF 2.5 from java classes)
2. smartGWT client application

If I use SoapUI for call operation getUser, then everything works fine. 
But if I call operation getUser via my smartGWT app then I get this Exception:

```
WARNING: Interceptor for {http://serviceImpl.tuke.sk/}UserManagementServiceImplService has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error reading XMLStreamReader.
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:237)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:263)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:123)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:206)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:213)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:193)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:184)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:107)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:163)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.throwUnexpectedEOF(StreamScanner.java:677)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.handleEOF(BasicStreamReader.java:2104)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextFromProlog(BasicStreamReader.java:2010)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1102)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.nextTag(BasicStreamReader.java:1125)
    at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.ReadHeadersInterceptor.handleMessage(ReadHeadersInterceptor.java:138)
    ... 23 more
2.11.2011 19:56:34 org.apache.cxf.services.UserManagementServiceImplService.UserManagementServiceImplPort.UserManagementService
```

In the logs I have this:

request:

```
ID: 2
Address: http://localhost:8080/healthCard/userManagementService
Encoding: UTF-8
Http-Method: POST
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Headers: {Accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], accept-charset=[ISO-8859-2,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], accept-language=[sk,cs;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3], cache-control=[no-cache], connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[0], content-type=[text/xml; charset=UTF-8], cookie=[__utma=111872281.318978992.1316156803.1317062005.1317851878.15; __utmz=111872281.1316156804.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)], host=[localhost:8080], pragma=[no-cache], referer=[http://localhost:8080/healthCardGui/index.html], SOAPAction=[""], user-agent=[Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1]}
--------------------------------------
```

response:

```
ID: 2
Response-Code: 500
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: text/xml
Headers: {}
Payload: <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader.</faultstring></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--------------------------------------
```

And my code of calling webservice is this:

```
    XMLTools.loadWSDL("http://localhost:8080/healthCard/userManagementService?wsdl", new WSDLLoadCallback() {
      public void execute(WebService webService) {
          webservice = webService;
      }
    });

    return form;

  }

  class UserForm extends DynamicForm {
    public void callService() {
      if (webservice == null) {
        SC.say("Please try again in a moment  - still loading web service descriptor");
      } else {
        setValue("username", "Loading...");
        Map data = new LinkedHashMap();
        data.put("firstname", getValueAsString("username"));


        webservice.callOperation("getUser", data, null, new WebServiceCallback() {

          public void execute(Object[] data, JavaScriptObject xmlDoc, RPCResponse rpcResponse,
              JavaScriptObject wsRequest) {
            UserForm.this.setValue("username", (String) data[0]);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

**Could you help me with it please?**

Comment: What does your outbound XML look like? Looks like there is an error in the XML syntax.